# Quartz.net periodically recycle IIS application pool

Tags: quartz.net

I have one Quartz.net window service and asp.net web application hosting in same server.

Quartz.net window service periodically recycle IIS application pool and web application user got session time out. If I stopped the Quartz.net window service and then there is no session time out for web application user.

I have no idea why Quartz.net window service recycle IIS application pool since Scheduler is hosted as window service.

The only thing I can think of it is that web application and Quartz share same business logic dll.

Any one experienced this issue?

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Have you checked the application and systems logs for errors at the time of recycling?

Comment: Have a look at my answer on [Quartz.net scheduler doesn't fire jobs/triggers once deployed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196717/quartz-net-scheduler-doesnt-fire-jobs-triggers-once-deployed/33672149#33672149). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your Quartz.net window service perform any of the actions specified in:

[What causes an application pool in IIS to recycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302110/what-causes-an-application-pool-in-iis-to-recycle)

For example, if your window service is creating directories in the directory in which your web application resides, it will cause the corresponding application pool to recycle.

Comment: @ZurbThanks but it did not worked for me as indicated on [Cannot keep alive Web Application on IIS after Recycling or Restarting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593602/cannot-keep-alive-web-application-on-iis-after-recycling-or-restarting). Any help pls?