# Quartz.net Job not firing in deployment mode but firing in debug mode

Tags: asp.net, iis, cron, quartz.net

I have a Quartz.net job that sends emails every 5 minutes. It runs perfectly fine when I *run* the application in debug mode locally. But when deploy to the server, the job is not running. Can someone think of a reason why?

Our deployed sites are ASP.NET websites in IIS.

Comment: Does it reproduce only on your server or locally under IIS it also reproduces?

Comment: It reproduces on my local server as well as two staging servers. But not on production server. It works fine there.

Comment: Have a look at my answer on [Quartz.net scheduler doesn't fire jobs/triggers once deployed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196717/quartz-net-scheduler-doesnt-fire-jobs-triggers-once-deployed/33672149#33672149). Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't exactly what caused the issue. I spend quite a bit of time on this but could not find why the job was not running. Eventually I looked at the log and found that the job that was run ahead of it was throwing some kind of exception, **so I moved my job from last in the list to first in the list and it started working fine**. There were a couple of weird things that happened as well and I was not *completely* satisfied how it got resolved. Other things that I think of was

- We had a number of environments (dev, staging, staging), it is possible there was some kind of conflict caused by these multiple environments however I think it is unlikely

Anyways the job start running fine after I reorder the job. The interesting thing was, I fixed the ordering in a branch and it got fixed in dev and staging environments.

Comment: Thanks but it did not worked for me as indicated on [Cannot keep alive Web Application on IIS after Recycling or Restarting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593602/cannot-keep-alive-web-application-on-iis-after-recycling-or-restarting). Any help pls?

Answer (score 0):

Wire up these two "built in" listeners....

```
<add key="quartz.plugin.jobHistory.type" value="Quartz.Plugin.History.LoggingJobHistoryPlugin, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.plugin.triggHistory.type" value="Quartz.Plugin.History.LoggingTriggerHistoryPlugin, Quartz" />
```

You'll need to wire up the ILog stuff.

Then you'll be able to figure out what is and is not happening.

```
<configSections>

    <sectionGroup name="common">
        <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
    </sectionGroup>

</configSections>
<common>
    <logging>
        <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.NLog20">
            <arg key="configType" value="FILE" />
            <arg key="configFile" value="~/NLog.config" />
        </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
</common>
```

NLog.config

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" internalLogFile="Nlog.log">
    <targets>
        <target name="logfileTargetName" xsi:type="File"   layout="${longdate}|${level}|${callsite}|${logger}|${threadid}|${windows-identity:domain=false}__${message} ${exception:format=message,stacktrace:separator=*"
                fileName="MyNLogLogFile.txt" />

    </targets>
    <rules>

        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfileTargetName"/>

    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just posted my own answer as it got resolved eventually after too much investigation.