# ASP .net core scheduler shutting down before compete the task

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, quartz.net

I have scheduled task configured using Quartz.net in asp.net core application. I did my implementation as mentioned in this article [Creating a Quartz.NET hosted service with ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/creating-a-quartz-net-hosted-service-with-asp-net-core/)

When the scheduled task starts it runs for 10-15 mins and its shutting down. In the log file it mentioned as follows.

```
Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler|INFO|Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler|INFO|Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
```

I changed the IIS application pool settings as mention in this question[IIS Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196717/quartz-net-scheduler-doesnt-fire-jobs-triggers-once-deployed) but its not worked either. I am using .net core 2.1 version

Comment: https://medium.com/@daniel.sagita/backgroundservice-for-a-long-running-work-3debe8f8d25b

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. I installed the Application Initialization module via the Server Manager. The module under Server Roles -> Web Server -> Application Developer -> Application Initialization.
After that I made the changes as mentioned in [IIS Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196717/quartz-net-scheduler-doesnt-fire-jobs-triggers-once-deployed)